# How to give administrator rights in Java code for tasks

Tags: java, filereader, admin-rights

There was such a problem. With the help of FileReader I run on the system file and try to change the lines in it. But I can not do this if my application is not running on behalf of the administrator.

```
private BufferedReader fileReader(String path) {
   FileReader fileReader = null;
   try {
       fileReader = new FileReader(path);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
   return bufferedReader;
}

private String fileWriter(String path) {
   try {
       BufferedReader bR = fileReader(filePath);
       while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null) {
          ...
          ...
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return result;
}
```

Help me how to request elevation of the rights in the code so that when using my program, not on behalf of the administrator, I did not need to restart it with elevated privileges for correct work?

OS: Windows

But I would like to get a General solution, if there is one, because the application is used on different platforms

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @GhostCat, sorry, forgot to write. OS-Windows. But I would like to get a General solution, if there is one, because the application is used on different platforms

Comment: If you could do this programmatically, it's a security hole

Comment: By the way, you forgot to close the BufferedReader in a finally block

Comment: @cricket_007, in fact, all right, I'm just out of context piece of code ripped out to represent tasks)

Comment: @cricket_007, then help as it is possible to make it not programmatically. Create.* exe my method and run through cmd as Administrator? But there is the same application that causes the UAC when you run something?

Comment: It's not really clear what files you're trying to read, but you don't need exe. You can start an admin cmd and run `java` command

Comment: @cricket_007, *.ini which has read-only access. It must be ruled

Comment: One can wrap a java application (jar) as **_service_**. Then install the service as Administrator, and the normal user can start the computer and login under normal user privileges.